# Is this grammatical: "increasing pace at which"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is this grammatical:

> An understanding is seen as vital due to the increasing pace at which the world's markets are integrating.

Comment: I'm afraid proofreading is off topic, as explained in the [faq].

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's grammatical. If it's your sentence, you can rewrite it as **An understanding is seen as vital because of the increasing pace of the integration of the world's markets.** This seems to me to be a bit smoother and less stilted.